# About a theorem of tensor from Lang's Linear Algebra 2nd Edition

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

[image]

This is Theorem 1 about tensor from Lang's Linear Algebra 2nd Editon.

I think that the proof of TP2 is not correct because $(v, w) \mapsto v \otimes w$ is not surjective.

Is Lang's proof of TP2 correct or not?

I cannot understand why the statement "Hence the elements $v_i^{'} \otimes w_j^{'}$ generate $T$ over $K$" is correct.

Comment: Why is that map not surjective?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Note that the image of $V\times W$ under the mapping is a subset of $T$. Lang is not claiming $V\times W$ is all of $T$.

Comment: Mark and Jacky Chong, Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot understand why the statement "Hence the elements $v_i^{'} \otimes w_j^{'}$ generate $T$ over $K$" is correct.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much. Each $v_i \otimes v_j$ is a linear combination of the vectors $v_i^{'} \otimes w_j^{'}$.